# c++ static initialization order fiasco

Tags: c++, constants, static-members, static-initialization, static-order-fiasco

I'm currently learning C++, and I'm having some troubles.

I've developped a program by using lots of `#define`, but I'd like to use `static const` instead (collision/type/scopes...).

So, I now have something like:

`file1.hpp`

```
 class A {
   public:
     static const std::string MY_CONST_VAR;
 };
```

`file1.cpp`

```
 const std::string A::MY_CONST_VAR = "some string";
```

`file2.cpp`

```
 static std::string arrayOfString[] = {
   A::MY_CONST_VAR,
   ...
  };
```

My code compiles with no warnings/errors (compiling with -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror flags).

However, when I try to run it, it results in a segfault.

I've ran it with valgrind, and it gave me the following ouput:

```
==11239== Invalid read of size 4
==11239==    at 0x5F525CB: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==11239==    by 0x40D076: _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN16GraphicInterface13DEFAULT_WIDTHE (GraphicInterface.cpp:42)
==11239==    by 0x51AC7C: __libc_csu_init (in /home/simon/PSU_2013_zappy/gui/gui_zappy)
==11239==    by 0x66D8E54: (below main) (libc-start.c:246)
==11239==  Address 0xfffffffffffffff8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

So, the segfault occurs during the arrayOfString instanciation. I think the problem is that the arrayOfInt is allocated before the constant. But in that case, is it possible to use static const for this purpose?

I don't know how to patch this issue.
Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better way to do it? How to solve this issue?

Comment: "segfault occurs during the arrayOfInt instanciation"? What made you to conclude that? The valgrind report indicates that something happened in `std::basic_string` constructor. I don't see any uses of `std::basic_string` in the code you posted and it is certainly not `arrayOfInt`.

Comment: check the faq on [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

Comment: @AndreyT I've used int in my example, but I'm using string in my program. That's why i've concluded this. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: are you able to make use of constexpr? if yes, declaring the constant as such may solve your issue.

Comment: Try naming file1.o before file2.o in the linker command.

Comment: Generally you should try to avoid dynamic initialization of static variables in C++ (in file scope) that are not self-contained, i.e. initializing static variables with constructors that call external systems. std::string calls memory manager thus it falls into that category. It's just so easy to shoot yourself to foot with such a usage.

Comment: @Simon Ninon: `int` and `string` are *catastrophically* different in that regard. `int` supports static initialization, while `string` requires dynamic one. By replacing `string` with `int` you completely changed the semantics of your example. Don't replace. Post real code.

Comment: @AndreyT Yeah, that was a bad idea to change it. I thought it would simplify the code. But now I know the type of the issue, I understand it was a mistake.

Comment: Also see [AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco).

Comment: @EJP That's meaningless. The order between translation units is undefined. If that happens to work with a particular compiler, big deal; actually using it in production would indicate awful, hopelessly brittle code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I finally solved the problem by using `constexpr` keyword.

It gives me the following working code:

`file1.hpp`

```
class A {
  public:
    static constexpr char MY_CONST_VAR[] = "some string";
};
```

`file1.cpp`

```
const char A::MY_CONST_VAR[];
```

`file2.cpp`

```
static std::string arrayOfString[] = {
  A::MY_CONST_VAR,
  ...
};
```

Comment: But `constexpr` was introduced only in C++11. Good luck with portability.

Comment: It's in a C/C++ school project context where compatibility does not matter. Otherwise, I would make some wrappers around static variables, as it was mentioned earlier in the comments.

Comment: no no, keep using it, so that everyone raises the bar on compilers =)

Comment: @Kaz: "Good luck with portability" If in 2014 we don't consider C++11 "portable" and continue to code in C'96... It will never become.

Comment: Er, no. What actually fixed your problem was changing `std::string`, a type that requires dynamic initialisation, to `const char[]`, a type that does not. Adding `expr` might be more correct technically, but I'm 99% sure it has no relevance and made no difference whatsoever to the problem of (not) ordering the dynamic initialisation of `static` objects.

Answer (score 3):

A generic workaround for static-init-fiasco problems is to wrap the static in a function, because variables inside functions do not have their initializers evaluated until the function is called.

That's not quite so straightforward when it's an array whose length is determined by the number of initializers. However, IMHO it is a poor design to access a global C-style array: either you have to pollute your code with range checks every time you use the array, or you risk doing an out-of-bounds access;  and array bound errors are some of the hardest errors to debug at runtime.

Personally I'd replace the code with:

```
std::string &lookup_string(size_t n)
{
    static std::string arrayOfString[] = { A::MY_CONST_VAR(), .... };

    if ( n >= dimof(arrayOfString) ) throw....
    return arrayOfString[n];
}
```

And also in the other file, if `constexpr` is unavailable:

```
std::string MY_CONST_VAR() { return "some string"; }
```

Now there are no static fiascoes .

NB. I'm assuming you want write access to `arrayOfString`, since you didn't declare it `const`. If they are supposed to be read-only then further improvements can be made.

Comment: Yes to the `generic workaround` part, so (+) ...but, honestly, I find constants (especially when UPPER_CASED) look rather bad with parentheses after it - do you *really* like it?